# Wordpress slow query on wp_posts

Tags: mysql, wordpress, performance

We have a wordpress with a database with 2 million records in wp_posts, new relic is showing that we have several slow queries but this one is taking

```
 SELECT wp_posts.ID 
 FROM wp_posts  
 WHERE ?=?  AND wp_posts.post_type = ? AND ((wp_posts.post_status = ?))  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title ASC 
 LIMIT ?, ?
```

And it's explaining this:

[image]

I don't know exactly how can I optimize this query but I guess I need to add an index with (id, post_type, post_status, and post_title)?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `INDEX(type, status, title, ID)`.  But that won't work because you cannot have a `TEXT` (as in `post_title`) column in an index.

So there is no optimization and no useful index.

WP is not designed to scale.  2M rows is a lot, though not so bad as it would be if you were joining to `postmeta` or other tables.

This query needs to collect all the titles of a certain type and status, sort them, skip over the `OFFSET`, and finally deliver some IDs.

If you are using `OFFSET` because of "pagination", then you have a second problem -- the query will be slower and slower as the user pages through the list.  (Notice the "skip" step I mentioned.)

*If* you could limit titles to under 255 (or maybe 191, depending on version and charset) characters, then the `INDEX` I mentioned will work, and it will work a lot faster.  That would involve and `ALTER TABLE` to change `post_title` to `VARCHAR(...)` which would take some time and lose data if any titles are truncated.

A possible solution...  Since it is not reasonable to deliver 2M rows to the user, can we guess that `type` and/or `status` is rather selective?  That is, are there really only at most a few hundred rows of interest?  In that case, this may help:

```
INDEX(post_type, post_status) -- in either order.
```